# When using mssql queries in Nodejs, Can't I use it like mysql2?

Tags: node.js, express

I used queries very simply when used mysql2 in Nodejs.

`('select * from table where A = ? AND B = ?', [val1, val2])`

But I'm using mssql this time, and it seems very uncomfortable.

```
const result = await pool.request()
.input('input_parameter', sql.Int, req.query.input_parameter)
.query('select * from mytable where id = @input_parameter')      

})
```

When using the mssql module, can't I use it as simple as mysql2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#es6-tagged-template-literals) the closest thing is the tagged template literal syntax:

```
const conn = await sql.connect(config);
const result = await conn.query`select * from table where A = ${val1} AND b = ${val2}`;
```

Since it's a [tagged template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates), not just a template string, the module can do sanitization for you. (Just be mindful of the syntax: not `conn.query(...)`.)

You can [see the implementation for those template strings here](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/blob/c77c80b7d90c172a76b7422dccce94e77607b06c/lib/base/request.js#L62-L98), if you're curious.

Comment: Thank you for responding.
If I use it, is there no risk for sql injection?

Comment: Thats what the docs say: "All values are automatically sanitized against sql injection. This is because it is rendered as prepared statement, and thus all limitations imposed in MS SQL on parameters apply."